# SSH authentication process

Tags: ssh

I use SSH to connect to a Linux server from my Windows OS computer. After I created another Windows user account in my local computer and I used SSH from the new account I found that it also reverts the

> The authenticify of host '...' can't be established ... ECDSA key fingerprint is ...

message which I understand should appear only once when it is the first time connecting to the server.

I am a beginner about SSH and my questions are:

1. What is an ECDSA key fingerprint?Is it the public key or the private key?
2. When I used my old Windows account to connect to the server by SSH, it does not give the message. Could I have a brieft outline of the phases of SSH authentication(and/or encryption) because I don't know what would affect the key generation. I just thought connecting from the same client(as I am using the same computer) would not prompt the warning message again.
3. Do I understand the concept of client correctly? Is it not just about the machine (e.g. IP) but also other things like Windows account, ... etc? would be good to know what constitutes a client completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.:

A *fingerprint* in this context is just the *hash of a public key*.

It is used as a compact representation of the server's public key to allow the user to check if the server uses the "correct" public key - i.e. the expected one. Only the server should ever have access to the corresponding private key.

ECDSA is one of various key formats, i.e. algorithms.

#### 2.:

The private/public key pair of the server is generated once, in most cases at install time. When a client connects to the server it will receive the public key of the server with which the client can encrypt the connection so only the server can decrypt it using the private key (see [*Public-key cryptography* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)).

To be sure that it is talking to the "right" server the client will lookup the fingerprint of public key it has locally saved for that specific server, which is by default in the file `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, see also the [`UserKnownHostsFile` option](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#UserKnownHostsFile).

If the fingerprint of the server doe not match the saved fingerprint the client aborts with a warning.

If the client has no saved fingerprint for that server it will ask the user whether they trust this public - optimally the user manually checks the fingerprint - and if so the client will save the trusted fingerprint to the `known_hosts` file -> this is what the message you're seeing means.

For further connections the client can then check `known_hosts` to see that the public key is already trusted. See also [*Trust on first use*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use).

#### 3.:

The *client* here is the `ssh` client, i.e. the program `ssh`. The `ssh` client includes configs [from various places](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#FILES), most notably from `~/.ssh/config` and the before mentioned `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

With `~` being the home directory *of the current user* the configuration file and the saved host fingerprints will be different for each OS user! But if you want to migrate your config and saved `known_hosts` you can simply copy/move `~/.ssh/` from the old to the new user.